# Why doesn't AlertDialog.Builder stay even after setCancelable(false) on some android devices? (eg: MI Pad)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

Why doesn't AlertDialog.Builder  stay for long even after using setCancelable(false) on some android devices? (eg: MI Pad). It is working fine for Samsung and Moto G3. This happens only when there is GCM.
The code i have used is below:

public void buildAlertMessageNotification(String message) {

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), R.style.mainActivityTheme));
    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    try {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                alertDialog.show();
                Looper.loop();

            }
        }.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```